# Trouble with Rails Unicorn Web Server starting on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, unicorn

I've been trouble-shooting my crashed application on Heroku without success.  I'm using:

- Ruby 2.1.0
- Rails 4.1.6
- Unicorn web server

I'm getting an Application Error when I go to my url.

These are the last few lines from `heroku logs`

```
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095469+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in      `new'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095481+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095477+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-    4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `build_app!'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095483+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095470+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095471+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095467+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095473+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095474+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:764:in `call'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.095480+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-13T20:44:36.912915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-13T20:44:37.040788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-13T20:45:09.859594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stand-as-witnesses-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=2228b811-6b37-482e-a1ec-630699947581 fwd="71.232.132.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Heroku ps gives:

```
=== web (1X): `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: crashed 2015/03/13 16:44:37 (~ 19m ago)
```

I upgraded from Ruby 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 and from Unicorn 4.6.3 to 4.8.3 to see if that would solve the problem, but no help there.

My Procfile and app/config/unicorn.rb files are standard based on Heroku's instructions for using unicorn.

Since the app runs fine locally, can anyone point out why I'm getting this crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you have provided only part of backtrace. Could you please provide all error backtrace from log?

Comment: The complete heroku logs result is shown here:  https://gist.github.com/lgrains/1f65ef9c3269ad470d65

Comment: Your problem [related to](https://gist.github.com/lgrains/1f65ef9c3269ad470d65#file-heroku_logs-L38) problem in `app/admin/blocked_site.rb`. Try to investigate why this AA file caused: `superclass mismatch for class BlockedSitesController (TypeError)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should specify model class instead (as I understand this is `BlockedSite`) of controller in your `app/admin/blocked_site.rb` AA file. This should fix error:

```
superclass mismatch for class BlockedSitesController (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It turns out that the problem was that we had an existing file in `app/controllers/admin/blocked_sites_controller.rb`.  When I removed that file and a couple of others in that same location, the crashes went away and I was able to navigate to my pages.